# How to properly use timeout parameter in select?

Tags: python, sockets, timeout

I'm new to socket programming (and somewhat to Python too) and I'm having trouble getting the select timeout to work the way I want to (on the server side). Before clients connect, timeout works just fine. I give it a value of 1 second and the timeout expires in my loop every 1 second.

Once a client connects, however, it doesn't wait 1 second to tell me the timeout expires. It just loops as fast as it can and tells me the timeout expires. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
while running:
    try:
        self.timeout_expired = False
        inputready, outputready, exceptready = select.select(self.inputs, self.outputs, [], self.timeout)
    except select.error, e:
        break
    except socket.error, e:
        break

    if not (inputready):
        # Timeout expired
        print 'Timeout expired'
        self.timeout_expired = True

    # Additional processing follows here
```

I'm not sure if this is enough code to see where my problem is, so please let me know if you need to see more. Basically, after a client connects, it at least *appears* that it ignores the timeout of 1 second and just runs as fast as it can, continuously telling me "Timeout expired". Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks much!!

Edit: I should clarify..."inputready" represents input from a client connecting or sending data to the server, as well as stdin from the server. The other variables returned from select are only server-side variables, and is what I'm trying to do is detect whether the CLIENT took too long to reply, so I'm only checking if inputready is empty.

Comment: If inputready, then the server loops through each socket in inputready and does additional processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is only a timeout if `inputready`, `outputready`, and `exceptready` are ALL empty.  My guess is you have added the client socket to both `self.inputs` and `self.outputs`.  Since the output socket is usually writable, it will always show up in `outputready`.  Only add the client socket to `self.outputs` if you are ready to output something.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. Yep, your guess was spot on. I've been using self.outputs to easily keep track of who to send messages to when I'm ready. I guess I can just loop through self.inputs and add them to self.outputs when I'm ready to output something to all clients...

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I ended up stuffing the outputs in another variable and throwing them all into self.outputs just before sending a message (then removing them after sending). Thankfully that could all be done from one spot >.< would've been a real pain otherwise. Thanks for your help! Saved me a ton of time later down the road if I hadn't fixed this now...

Answer (score 3):

"When the timeout expires, select() returns three empty lists. 
...To use a timeout requires adding the extra argument to the select() call and handling the empty lists after select() returns."

```
readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs,timeout)

if not (readable or writable or exceptional):
    print('  timed out, do some other work here', file=sys.stderr)
```

[https://pymotw.com/3/select/index.html][1]

Comment: @MauricioContreras It may answer your question, but not the OP's question.  I'm not the downvoter, but it is probably why it was downvoted.  The OP never got a timeout, but was expecting one, and it was due to not selecting properly.